# Is this indexed approach to java rts game development valid and how can I improve it?

Tags: java, game-development, project-structure, real-time, java8

I have class `GameState` laid out to basically hold an Array of Players, an `Array` of `StarSystems`, and a few other fields that need to persist from save to save. Each `GameObject` keeps track of its own id, which is also its index in its array as well as the id's of relevant gameobjects.

```
public class GameState implements Json.Serializable
{
    private Array<StarSystem> systems;
    private Array<Player> players;

    //Methods used to access data and some utilities
}
```

Each `StarSystem` in the `GameState` stores an `Array` of `Planet`'s and a Star or three, which in turn hold information on temperature and habitablity. Class Star extends from Planet and has 0 habitablity. The `StarSystem` class also has references to all Fleets present in the system, their owners. `Fleet` class holds a list of Ship instances that are in the fleet and relevant information for each ship.

I designed this system for two reasons:

1. I wanted to be able to call `Json.toJson(Object)` once when I save the game rather than go through and individually save every object.
2. Before this my code was very unorganized and I had weird references to various things strewn through the code. This is cleaner.

Unfortunately this has also dropped the FPS down from 35-40 to 20-25, which ticks me off and would probably tick any user off as well. In other words, I am asking how I can improve this design?

Notes: The indexed nature means that for a `Planet.ProductionQueue` to add a new `Fighter` to `Fleet` SomeFleet of `Player` A, it must first call `GameInstance.getInstance().getState().getSystem(parent_system).getFleet(fleet_target_id).addShip(new Fighter(owner_id, getLeastPowerfulCommandShip().getID()))`

Note that I am also using libGdx, and that the Json class I spoke of is part of the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the hierarchy of your game, the problem is that you are descending the entire hierarchy for every request.

I'm guessing that players look at a single system at a time, and that a player would "select" a fleet to add a Fighter to it.

Therefore, store local variables: `StarSystem current`, and `Fleet selected`  Update these variables when the player changes the current fleet/star system.  You don't need to descend the entire hierarchy to access an object.

Note: the objects selected should *still* be stored in the data structures you mentioned.

Comment: I started out doing this but the libGdx Json class sent me into an infinite loop when serializing/saving the game state. I tried customizing serialization using Json.Serializable, For example, I might have instantiated a Ship by passing the `Fleet` it is in into its constructor and adding it to a list of `Ship`'s in said `Fleet`. The problem occurred when I called `Json.toJson(fleet)` and it automatically read all the fields and tried to serialize them. It would, for example, read Ship[0] into a Json array and read its field `parentFleet` and serialize that into Ship[0] and so on and so forth.

Comment: I am writing a Stack Overflow question on how to fix this problem. I think this answers **why** it is dropping the rate, though.